# Unable to fetch members of a group (XMPP)

Tags: ios, swift, xmpp, chat

When a specific room is created by me, I can fetch members in that group. But when the group is created by someone else, I can't fetch members in that group.

The `didDiscoverRooms` method is initially called and then within it the members are fetched like so...

```
func xmppMUC(_ sender: XMPPMUC, didDiscoverRooms rooms: [Any], forServiceNamed serviceName: String) {
    print("XMPPRoom: didDiscoverRooms: \(rooms)")
    if let elements = rooms as? [DDXMLElement] {
      for element in elements {
        print("Name: \(String(describing: element.attributeStringValue(forName: "name")))")
        print("JID:  \(String(describing: element.attributeStringValue(forName: "jid")))")        
        if let name = element.attributeStringValue(forName: "jid"), let roomJID = XMPPJID(string: name) {
          let roomStorage = XMPPRoomMemoryStorage()
          let room = XMPPRoom(roomStorage: roomStorage!, jid: roomJID, dispatchQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
          room.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
          room.activate(self.xmppStream)
          room.fetchConfigurationForm()
          room.fetchMembersList()
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The `room.fetchMembersList()` in turn calls this delegate method..

```
  func xmppRoom(_ sender: XMPPRoom, didFetchMembersList items: [Any]) {
    print("XMPPRoom: \(sender.roomJID)")
    print("XMPPRoom: didFetchMembersList: \(items)")

  }
```

The first print statement gives the room name and the second print statement gives the room members. But this only works if the room is created by me. If the room is created by someone else then I can't get the members...

Comment: Hello, Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Fetching the member list (and the admin and owner list) usually requires owner permissions because it will leak the Jabber ID in anonymous rooms. Some modern servers (recent ejabberd versions for example) make an exception for non-anonymous and also allow regular participants to fetch that list.